# Timestamp string to datetime (python)

Tags: python, timestamp, python-datetime

I have this timestamp string:

```
x = 2021-11-24T16:05:51.399+0000
```

I am struggling to get the parsing to pass after the decimal point. Here is my attempt so far:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+")
```

Current error running this line:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 0000
```

Comment: a bit hacky but efficient: `datetime.fromisoformat(x[:-2] + ':' + x[-2:])` - [fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) needs the UTC offset to be in the form `hh:mm`, i.e. with the colon in-between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `%z` at the end of the format to match [*UTC offset in the form ±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]] (empty string if the object is naive).*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> x = '2021-11-24T16:05:51.399+0000'
>>> datetime.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 24, 16, 5, 51, 399000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```